# How do I properly add UI elements into a view programmatically for iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, uiview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin.iOS in Visual Studio 2013 to build a simple user interface programmatically in C#. I know it's much easier to use the designer view, but it's not working for me right now.

So far, I have managed to get the MPMoviePlayerController and the TextView showing, but the TextView won't scroll, even though I added requirements to do so.

The TextView overlaps the video as I can hear audio playing in the background. And the UILabel is no where to be seen.

I thought adding each UI element as a subView of the main View, will show the elements in a stack order displaying the video at the top, label right under the video and textview with scroll.

In a way, I want them to sort of stack each other layer by layer. What am I not doing right or am missing something?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using MediaPlayer;

public partial class VideoViewController : UIViewController
    {
        MPMoviePlayerController moviePlayer;
        UILabel label;
        UITextView textView;
        public VideoViewController() : base("VideoViewController", null)
        {
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            moviePlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController(NSUrl.FromString("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")); // Use FromString() to play video directly from web.
            moviePlayer.View.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 20, this.View.Frame.Size.Width, 180); // size of the video frame
            moviePlayer.ScalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFit; // show the video relative to the video size dimensions
            moviePlayer.PrepareToPlay();
            moviePlayer.Play();
            this.View.AddSubview(moviePlayer.View); // add the view after video starts playing to display it

            // UILabel
            label = new UILabel();
            label.Text = "Tutorial";
            label.Font.WithSize(36);
            this.View.AddSubview(label.ViewForBaselineLayout);

            // UITextView
            textView = new UITextView();
            textView.Editable = false;
            textView.ScrollEnabled = true;
            textView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
            textView.ViewForBaselineLayout.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, this.View.Frame.Size.Width, this.View.Frame.Size.Height*3);
            textView.Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. [shorten text for this post] "; // shorten text for this post
            this.View.AddSubview(textView);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting the frames for all of your UI components just like you did with the player, if the frame is undefined the result is gonna be unpredictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing you want it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using MediaPlayer;
using CoreGraphics;

namespace CHANGE_THIS_TO_YOUR_NAME_SPACE
{
    public partial class VideoViewController : UIViewController
    {
        MPMoviePlayerController moviePlayer;
        UILabel label;
        UITextView textView;

        public VideoViewController () : base ("VideoViewController", null)
        {
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            moviePlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController (NSUrl.FromString ("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")); // Use FromString() to play video directly from web.
            moviePlayer.View.Frame = new CGRect (0, 20, View.Frame.Size.Width, 180); // size of the video frame
            moviePlayer.ScalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFit; // show the video relative to the video size dimensions
            moviePlayer.PrepareToPlay ();
            moviePlayer.Play ();
            View.Add (moviePlayer.View); // add the view after video starts playing to display it

            // UILabel
            label = new UILabel (new CGRect(0,200, View.Frame.Size.Width, 50));
            label.Text = "Tutorial";
            label.Font.WithSize (36);
            View.Add (label.ViewForBaselineLayout);

            // UITextView
            textView = new UITextView ();
            textView.Editable = false;
            textView.ScrollEnabled = true;
            textView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
            textView.ViewForBaselineLayout.Frame = new CGRect (0, 250, View.Frame.Size.Width, View.Frame.Size.Height * 3);
            textView.Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. [shorten text for this post] "; // shorten text for this post
            View.Add (textView);

        }
    }
}
```

Basically you were almost there, when you are setting the frame for the view with a `CGRect` its `new CGRect(x-coord, y-coord, width, height)`. As all of the views were 0,0 they were place on top of each other. Also the `UITextView` wont scroll as you have made its height three times the height of the screen. If you want it to scroll the content(text) needs to extend past the frame.

iOS9 introduced `UIStackView`
See this video from WWDC 2015: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=218 but if you are supporting iOS7/8 there are some third party implementations. Xamarin.Forms has a stacklayout so that might be an option too.

An improved solution would be to not set the frame of your views and rather use auto layout constraints like so:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using MediaPlayer;
using CoreGraphics;

namespace CHANGE_THIS_TO_YOUR_NAME_SPACE
{
    public partial class VideoViewController : UIViewController
    {
        MPMoviePlayerController moviePlayer;
        UILabel label;
        UITextView textView;

        public VideoViewController () : base ("VideoViewController", null)
        {
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            moviePlayer = new MPMoviePlayerController (NSUrl.FromString ("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")); // Use FromString() to play video directly from web.
            moviePlayer.View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
//          moviePlayer.View.Frame = new CGRect (0, 20, View.Frame.Size.Width, 180); // size of the video frame
            moviePlayer.ScalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFit; // show the video relative to the video size dimensions
            moviePlayer.PrepareToPlay ();
            moviePlayer.Play ();
            View.Add (moviePlayer.View); // add the view after video starts playing to display it

            // UILabel
//          label = new UILabel (new CGRect(0,200, View.Frame.Size.Width, 50));
            label = new UILabel ();
            label.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
            label.Text = "Tutorial";
            label.Font.WithSize (36);
            View.Add (label.ViewForBaselineLayout);

            // UITextView
            textView = new UITextView ();
            textView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
            textView.Editable = false;
            textView.ScrollEnabled = true;
            textView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
//          textView.ViewForBaselineLayout.Frame = new CGRect (0, 250, View.Frame.Size.Width, View.Frame.Size.Height * 3);
            textView.Text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. [shorten text for this post] "; // shorten text for this post
            View.Add (textView);

            SetUpAutoLayoutConstraints ();
        }

        private void SetUpAutoLayoutConstraints()
        {
            View.AddConstraints (new [] {
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(moviePlayer.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(moviePlayer.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 0.5625f, 0), // setting it to this to keep your aspect ratio
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(moviePlayer.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 20),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(moviePlayer.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 0)
            });

            View.AddConstraints (new [] {
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(label, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(label, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, null, NSLayoutAttribute.NoAttribute, 1, 50),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(label, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, moviePlayer.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(label, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 0)
            });

            View.AddConstraints (new [] {
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(textView, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(textView, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(textView, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, label, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint.Create(textView, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 0)
            });

        }
    }
}
```

This then lets your view adapt to the screen size, e.g. layout on iphone4,5,6,6+ iPad properly. and your `UITextView` will scroll if its too big.

A Good tutorial on auto layout [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up! However, nothing is showing on screen (just a white blank screen). I'm puzzled.

Comment: Thats weird you could try deleting the `partial` part in the class declaration, then remove the xib files and designer.cs file as you dont needs these as you are setting up the view programmatically. If that doesnt work would you be able to edit your question with where you add the view?

Comment: Thanks again for your generous help. Everything is working now as expected.